# Wordpress users keep disappearing

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the strangest problem, never encountered before. My users are disappearing. They are somehow being deleted so no record of them in database remains. Every couple of days one or two users disappear. The user accounts are created through woocommerce. [woocommerce-my-account]
Does anyone have idea?

Comment: This is a site for asking and answering questions about programming. Your question would be better for a Wordpress support site or forum.

Comment: probably you've been hacked. or somebody is trying to hack you right now. that is how sql injection could looks like.